# Binary Corrupted in AWS Functions with .Net Core when upload

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services

My code return the first 6 bytes. When I upload a text file it works fine, but if I upload a binary file, locally work fine but in AWS Lambda return 3 bytes `[239,191,189]` (replacement char �) to each binary byte .

For example, a PNG file always starts with "‰PNG\r\n" , in decimal is  `[137,80,78,71,13,10]` bytes, local work fine but into AWS Lambda give-me `[239,191,189,80,78,71]` because the 137 byte is replaced by 3 bytes `[239,191,189]`. It is like the AWS Lambda not worked with binary files.

My code is:

```
[HttpPost("upload")]
[DisableRequestSizeLimit]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<String> Upload([FromForm(Name = "file")] IFormFile file )
{
    byte[] buffer = null;
    BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(file.OpenReadStream());
    buffer = reader.ReadBytes((int)file.Length);
    return "[" + buffer[0] + "," + buffer[1] + "," + buffer[2] + "," + buffer[3] + "," + buffer[4] + "," + buffer[5] + "]"; 

}
```

In the AWS Gateway binnary types I put multipart-form and *

Comment: How are you hooking this code up to Lambda?

Comment: I am deploying using the Visual Studio AWS Plugin.

Comment: `[239,191,189]` is not �. � is the unicode replacement character that is used when an unknown unicode character is detected.

Comment: Yes, but why is replaced if is a binnary file? And why the diference between local and aws server?